# Struts Wildcard Mappings not working after upgrading to 2.5.26

Tags: java, struts2

I have a action class that uses wild card mappings. it was working in struts 2.5.22, but I tried upgrading to 2.5.26 (and 2.5.25) and now setType is never called.

```
@Component
@Namespace("/applications/proxy")
@Flow(purgeAllBefore = "Y")
@Action(value = "{type}")
@Results({@Result(name = "input", type = "dispatcher", location = "/jsp/applications/proxy.jsp"),
          @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction", location = "${type}", params = {"namespace", "/applications"}),
          @Result(name = "auto-select", type = "redirectAction", location = "${autoSelectUrl}", params = {"namespace", "/"})})
public class ProxyAction extends SearchSupport {
  // Struts wildcard action mapping variable for the attachment, for example: 'J', 'R', 'I', 'N', 'H'
  private String type;
 
  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }
 
  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
...
```

Comment: This is not the question if you didn't provide any related information including error, server logs, etc. If your problem is only version of Struts then you should read release notes. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729041/573032) answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found the problem. this line is needed in the strutsconfig file, but not in the documentation:

```
<constant name="struts.matcher.appendNamedParameters" value="true"/>
```